# Making the color under the status bar match, when using Drawer Layout

Tags: android, material-design, navigation-drawer, statusbar

I'm having the hardest time changing the color beneath the transparent status bar color. The transparency is fine when the drawer is open, but the color beneath is wrong. Different fragments are going to have different action bar colors.

`fitsSystemWindow` has no effect.

Changing the status bar color just makes it solid.

If I set a color with a lower alpha, it just mixes with the green (Primary Color Dark).

What is happening: (Color underneath is green)

[image: full screenshot of incorrect colour] [image: closeup screenshot of incorrect colour]

What I want is exactly like what is happening in the play store:

[image: screenshot example 1 of correct colour from play store] [image: screenshot example 2 of correct colour from play store]

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding ur question, whenever user changes fragment you can tell activity to change the status bar color accordingly?

Comment: @Max
So yes on fragment change I can do.
 - getWindow().setStatusBarColor(color);
But that makes it a solid color, and I lose the transparent effect when the drawer opens

Comment: I added another picture to hopefully help.
But my first fragment is green, So the green under the transparent works fine. But when I change fragments with a different color, the color underneath is still green.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following should do what you want:

- First make sure that your app theme in `v21/style.xml` has

  ```
  <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
  ```
- Use `mDrawerLayout.setStatusBarBackgroundColor()` for changing the background color of `statusBar` on fragment change instead of `setStatusBarColor()`.
- Make sure your `coordinatorLayout` doesn't contain the property `android:fitsSystemWindows`.

Comment: Thanks bud, yeah just realized that there was already built int. I kept just using setStatusBarColor().

One of those days where i wasted so much time... Thanks

Comment: lol I only realized it ur using the other one when you mentioned it in comments :)